# Discord calls will make Ubuntu laggy

Tags: 20.04, voip

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for 3 days now and noticed that every time I'm in a Discord call/voice channel, my whole desktop will hiccup on simple tasks like writing code or browsing the web.

I know for a fact that the issue is related to Discord because if I disconnect the call/voice channel, the whole experience goes back to normal.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Please post hardware specifications. At first glance you don't have enough resources.

Comment: Do you use the discord app or the browser version? If its the app, how did you install it? Did you try the other option? (I use the App installed via Snap and have no issues)

Comment: It shouldn't be an hardware issue. I have a 1500$ Desktop. Oh and I tried installing the app through ubuntu software and discord website. Both behave the same. I'll try it your way,